# Removing base model relations in Loopback 3

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm having a little bit of trouble when attempting to remove relations
from a model that uses another custom model as its base. Assuming the following
setup

```
// Item Model, item.json
...
"relations": {
    "parent": {"type": "belongsTo", "model": "Holder"}
}
...
```

```
// Special Item Model, item.json
...
"base": "Item",
"excludeBaseProperties": ["parentId"],
...
"relations": {}
...
```

When I look the `Special Item` model I find that the parentId still exists and
it even shows up in the relations.

What is the proper way to remove parent model relations from a child Model in loopback 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I felt a bit silly about posting the question now because I figured one way to solve it a little while after posting it.

I'm posting my solution here, would appreciate if anyone can review it:

1. Create a module called `clear-relations.js`
2. Use the following bit of code inside it -

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Model) {
    // Get the attribute names of the inherited relations
    // and then explicitly delete them

    Object.keys(Model.settings.relations).forEach(relation => {
        delete Model.settings.relations[relation];
    });
}
```

3. If you don't already have a .js file for your model, create one then use the following bit of code

```
const ClearRelations = require("path/to/clear-relations.js");

module.exports = function(MyModel) {
    ClearRelations(MyModel);
}
```

Seems pretty easy once I figured it out. Hope this helps someone.